# Why so many AWS SQS requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-billing

Building a simple, mostly serverless app using two AWS SQS queues. One incoming lambda pushes data to an incoming queue for an EC2 to process when available. That EC2 process pushes processed data to another queue, which then triggers another lambda to notify requesting client.

Somehow, less a week into the month, the SQS service has accumulated over 200k "requests".

Messages from both queues are deleted once messages are received (respectively, from the EC2 process and the second lambda).

Why are there so many requests?

[image: Billing Info]

Comment: Don't get too worried -- Amazon SQS only charges 40c per million requests. A request can be used to send, receive and delete messages. This means that a single message might consume 3 requests. Plus, if Lambda is continually polling for messages, there might be a request every 20 seconds (which is the duration for Long Polling).

Comment: Yes, I found on AWS forum similar info: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=876982&tstart=0